# JSLint: "'HTMLElement' was used before it was defined."

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint: "'HTMLElement' was used before it was defined."

```
if (element instanceof HTMLElement)
```

How do I fix this?

Do I have to add an exception or ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check "Tolerate misordered definitions".

This works for me if my entire script is:

```
var e;
if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
    alert("");
}
```

and the *only* checked box is "Tolerate misordered definitions".

The response I get is:

```
Global HTMLElement, alert, e
```

This checkbox only seems to apply to identifiers used in the global scope.  If this is tried within a function body, JSLint will complain about `alert` unless you check the box to "Assume console, alert".  However the following trick *does* satisfy JSLint:

```
var HTMLElement = HTMLElement;
(function () {
    var e;
    if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
        alert("");
    }
}());
```

This passes with checkboxes "Assume console, alert", "Tolerate misordered definitions", and "Tolerate missing use strict."  I get the response:

```
Global HTMLElement  
3 'anonymous'()
    Variable e
    Global HTMLElement
    Complexity 2
```

Definitely a hack; `/*global HTMLElement */` is best.  Makes sense, though, after reading the JSLint instructions.

Comment: I checked all of the boxes except "Safe Subset" and "Verify ADsafe". I still got the error.

Comment: Odd... works for me.  But I edited my answer to sbow that I _only_ checked the one box and used just a four-line script....

Comment: Yeah, I tried your example and didn't get the error. I got the error when I wrapped in anonymous function. Can you try that?

Comment: @XP1, yes in an anonymous function many more errors kick in; I now get `Undefined variable: HTMLElement 1 'anonymous'`.  JSLint is much more tolerant about these things at the top-level.  I wonder why....

Comment: @XP1, I did a little more playing around with this and edited the answer.  Best fix though is to add the exception `/*global HTMLElement */` as it is cleaner than defining.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll have to add an exception for it. I could not find any of the checkbox options that remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add HTMLElement to the predefined textbox at the bottom of the JSLint page (if you are using the online validation version).

Since I'm assuming you are in a browser this should be a valid exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

change "alert" to "window.alert", and use the jslint directive /*jslint browser:true */ at the top.